# Wait Until Partial Text is present in Appium (Python)

Tags: python, appium, wait

Is there any way to wait for partial text "Score: 100%" to be present at least on the screen or appeared in the specified element id?
The whole element text looks like: "Answered: x/y, Score: N%" and it changes with a delay.
I need to execute the next command only after the Score gets 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text_to_be_present_in_element` from `ExpectedConditions` to accomplish this.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "myElementId"), "Score: 100%"))
```

Comment: That's what I really wanted to achieve! Thank you so much.